# Which SharePoint / Office 365 Plan suits best

Tags: sharepoint-online, subscriptions

For the company i work for we are thinking about the best way to create a SharePoint online OTAP.

The acceptation and production platform(office 365 & SharePoint Online) is Managed by the customer.

For development i have the following package: Office 365 developer subscription it is ok but you only can have one user on that subscription?

The real question here is what can i do best for development and test environment. We want to have the dev and test still separate.

What plans suits best for dev? and which one for test?

Answer (score 0):

In below link office 365 different plans has been give. For different test and customer environment in one plan also you can create 2 different site collection or you can purchase 2 different plan.

https://products.office.com/en-au/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans

Users account you can purchase separately based on your requirement.

Comment: i know the plans yes. Been watching to them for ages now but i don't know for sure what i can do best. I need a development environment with 3 users and a test environment  with 2 users.

Comment: You can create 2 different site collection in one plan. No need to purchase 2 plan for that.

Comment: Yeah but we would to have it completely seperated from each other no connection at all

Comment: To select Office 365 Plan is based on project and organization requirement. If you only want to use SharePoint Online site you can go with basic E1 plan and based on your user need you can purchase user license.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but still i will give the best possible options at a very high level.

if your organization wants more advanced features such as exchange online, one drive,Skype for business, compliance features such as Data loss protection and audit logs along with SharePoint online then you need **plan-3**

else if you just need SharePoint online and with its own advanced features like BCS, auditing and compliance,excel online and info-path then you need **Plan-2**.

Now, **Plan-1** will be least or stripped down version only limited to SharePoint online with above features. so if your organization and its users can live that then that's more than enough with only SharePoint online.

In any case, You need to integrate SharePoint online with your organization Active directory via Directory Sync services or you may configure ADFS as well. here the main point is you cant have two subscriptions synced the same active directory.it has some restrictions so go through the Microsoft documentation on the infrastructure needs before going in to purchasing part.

and finally, **MSDN based office 365 developer subscription** is ideal and fits well for the development purposes and to experience the ongoing roll outs. you can even integrate that with azure active directory (MSDN or your subscription) and have it used by multiple people. refer this excellent blog and i have implemented in my test tenant and provided access to multiple people. [Reference Link](http://www.edutech.me.uk/microsoft/identity-and-access-management/active-directory/link-microsoft-office-365-organization-account-to-windows-azure-subscription/)